# Reset time.Time in mgo struct

Tags: go, mgo

Simplified struct:

```
type User struct {
    ResetToken     string        `bson:"resettoken,omitempty" json:"resettoken"`
    ResetSent      time.Time     `bson:"resetsent,omitempty" json:"resetsent"`
}
```

Now on successful (password) reset it should set ResetToken = "" and
set ResetSent to "uninitialized" aka 0 or initial value or empty, you name it.

In the case of string it's done with "" and ",omitempty"
but how do I do with with time.Time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time zero is `time.Time{}`, and you can check that it's zero with `time.IsZero(t)`. So, something like:

```
user.ResetSent = time.Time{}
```

If you need it to really `omitempty`, you could use a `*time.Time`, so it will leave it empty if nil.

Update:
   Gustavo's comment is correct, `omitempty` works as intended for zero-valued time, without a pointer.

Comment: Please note that there's no need to use a pointer to have `omitempty` working for `time.Time`. `mgo/bson` will itself call `IsZero` to tell whether it is "empty" or not.

Comment: You're right. I could have sworn it didn't work for me when I tested.